# How to get Selected Row Cell Values From RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I want to get selected row cell values using RepositorySearchLookUpEdit but i don't know how to get it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access an edit value, use the [SearchLookUpEdit.EditValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.EditValue.property) property. This value corresponds to a value contained in the [ValueMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ValueMember.property) datasource column.

If you wish to access any cell value from a selected row, use the [SearchLookUpEdit.Properties.GetRowByKeyValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemGridLookUpEditBase.GetRowByKeyValue.method) method. You will need to pass the current edit value there. Then, cast this method return value to your data row type and access cell values.

Comment: I tried and it gives me exception 
using following code
 string s = RepositoryFabricId.GetRowByKeyValue(RepositoryFabricId.ValueMember).ToString();

Comment: RepositoryFabricId.ValueMember is just a string identifying what field contains the value member for the control. You need to pass an actual value (like the value of an identity field) to the method, not the name of the field.

Comment: You need to pass an edit value to this method, not a field name. To access an edit value, use the SearchLookUpEdit.EditValue property. If you are using a repository item in an editor container like GridControl, a cell editor is created only for a focused cell. Clarify at which moment you need to access this value and where your repository item is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to read columns from the selected row of your `LookupEdit` repository on a `GridView`, you can do that in the `CloseUp` event of the RepositoryEdit like this

```
private void RepositoryFabricId_CloseUp(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CloseUpEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseMode == DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupCloseMode.Normal)
    {
        DataRow row = ((GridLookUpEdit)sender).Properties.View.GetDataRow(((GridLookUpEdit)sender).Properties.View.FocusedRowHandle);
    }
}
```

This example is for a GridLookupEdit repository, I guess it will also work for a LookupEdit repository

Comment: @AyeshaSheikh No problem, glad I could help. Also consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it helped you